# Laravel language switcher, routes setup

Tags: laravel, localization

I want to use routes `example.com/en/item` fon english,  then call `example.com/no/item` 
my current controller:

```
class LocalizationController extends Controller
{
    public function switch($locale)
    {
        App::setLocale($locale);
        session(['locale'=> $locale]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => app()->getLocale()], function () {
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/threads', 'ThreadsController@index');
});
Route::get('/lang/{locale}','LocalizationController@switch');
```

How to keep locale showing in url?

Answer (score 1):

```
    return redirect(url()->previous()."?".http_build_query(['locale'=>$locale]));
```

or

```
    return redirect()->route('home', ['locale' => $locale]);
```

but in second example you must create name for your route, example:

```
Route::get('/lang/{locale}','PagesController@switch')->name('locale');
```

You will get something like this in your url:

> http://192.168.1.49/test/public/home?locale=en

Update:

Inside your .env set =>

```
APP_URL=en
```

> Inside app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

set this

```
   \URL::forceRootUrl(\Config::get('app.url'));
    if (\Str::contains(\Config::get('app.url'), 'https://')) {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

That after go to home page you will have in url

http://192.168.1.49/test/public/home/en

Comment: `?locale=en` is not what OP is after though

Comment: I was thinking about the way to redirect from `/` to `/en` on first load, then my url keeps locale in the place i want. But what about other routes?

Comment: What do you mean?After redirect your route group will be use setted locale and will be redirect to appropriate routes

Comment: How to load `example.com/en` instead of `example.com/`. Where changes should be done? in `.htaccess`, if yes how?